# Have a method for INPUT without using FORM in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm being creative and making something new. I am wanting to use `<input>` without `<form>` but don't think it's possible to make the input a method (POST) without using `<FORM>`. I'm currently trying to use

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    // Do Something
}
```

but having my input `<input type="button" name="name" />` does not activate the isset I have when using PHP to listen for that event.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there another way I should do this? I'm really lost, and don't have no idea what to do now. I do not want to use `<form>` since I'm currently not interested in using that. Should the input type be "submit"? What else is there I could do?

Comment: You cannot submit a form without the `<form>` tags. What is your objection to using them? Alternately, you could send the data using AJAX.

Comment: Generally, you would have a submit button. If you wish to go more complex into form submission, you'd use an Ajax call to send requests. I'd recommend going over the basics of forms first

Comment: Trying to do what you want to do would be like saying "I want to ride my bike to New York, without riding my bike" - you can't submit a form without a `<form>` in the page.

Comment: The only reason why I asked this is because input is usable without form, but was you able to get an output from it without using form. I only asked was this possible or not with php 5.5 or html5 since im not really updated on that yet. Im just having a sandbox creating cool things without using ordinary things. Just like creating a navigation menu (CSS) just using input and when post is used it will include a page. But thanks for letting me know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with a javascript onclick or onsubmit event, using GET rather than POST, but it's definitely not best practice.  Use a form or AJAX, as recommended by other posters:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="submit" onclick="javascript:window.location='http://yoururl.com/?name='+document.getElementById('name').value">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This will send it as `GET`, but could solve his issue easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to send a form data without using `<form>`.

The only way to do this is to use ajax instead of a classic HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

You can take inputs from STDIN in PHP's latest versions like:

`fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $value);`

Here **$value** will contain the input.

Comment: rollbacks are not there to undo improvements. Highlighting the full text as you did is seen as aggressiveness. Same as using full CAPITALIZED words is equal to YELLING or Screeming. I hope you now better understand the previous edit made by another user.